# Command find and convert using ffmpeg

Tags: macos, shell, command-line, ffmpeg

I would like to combine the two following commands to find mp4 files and convert them to mp3 and save them with same name.
The two command line:

```
find ./ -name '*.mp4'
ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -vn -acodec libmp3lame -ac 2 -ab 160k -ar 48000 audio.mp3
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

With `find`'s `-exec` functionality:

```
find ./ -name '*.mp4' -exec bash -c 'ffmpeg -i $0 -vn -acodec libmp3lame -ac 2 \
-ab 160k -ar 48000 ${0/mp4/mp3}' {} \;
```

This should make `xyz.mp4` to `xyz.mp3`.

Comment: Thanks, how I can delete the mp4 ?

Comment: `find ./ -name '*.mp4' -exec rm -f {} \;`, but check first if everything worked before deleting something.

Comment: Ahh sorry I didn't meant how to delete the files, I mean how to have the name without mp4 ex: {xyz.mp4 to xyz.mp3.}

Comment: @molwiko I edited the answer for this behavior. It now makes `xyz.mp4` to `xyz.mp3`.

Answer (score 0):

To just use the name without the extension add first `-exec sed -E s/.mp4$//g` followed by your `ffmpeg` command.